# Build Meteor in Docker cannot pass proxy setting

Tags: node.js, sockets, meteor, proxy, docker

I use latest Nodejs image as base image to build meteor project. The docker is behind the corporate proxy.

I tried curl and npm install -g. Both of them can go through the proxy and download packages.

However, when I try to use meteor update, error prompts as:

**Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)**
***=> Errors while upgrading packages:
error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up***

Then the next step is using run meteor build, and I sometimes also got the error as

***error: tunneling socket could not be established,
cause=140434436118336:error:140770FC:SSL
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:795:***

I test the proxy setting by echo it before I ran meteor command. It shown correctly.

Can anyone help? There is an bug fixes in meteor states that meteor can use http_proxy setting. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/3177d9ad416ae97a98a2b8c4b2b40a9fc03f6b9c

Comment: The problem turned out to be a proxy issue. Setting the proxy-https = http://<domain>:<port> can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found this to be an issue that occurs with docker across a couple of projects and solve it by simply restarting my docker machine (working on OSX)

`$ docker-machine restart dev`

Also [Meteor doesn't support the more recent versions of node](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3666) due in part to complexities associated with Fibers, you'll probably want to build your container `FROM node:0.10.40`